# Examples of finger painting/drawing apps for the iPad?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

What are some good examples/tutorials/code of finger painting or drawing applications?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

look at "GLPaint".

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLPaint/Introduction/Intro.html

the example is for iphone but its just a matter of layout.

shani

Answer (score -2):

Here's another one  It seems nice.

http://www.brushesapp.com/